# ajax load content with anchor-link? live-handler?

Tags: jquery, ajax, scroll, fragment-identifier, hashchange

hey guys,
i'm loading a div from a subsite with ajax. this subsite has a link in it like this:

```
<a href="#someIDonHomepage">anchorlink</a>
```

My homepage where the ajax request is fired has this #someIDonHomepage div and i want my page to jump to that position.

However since i'm loading the anchor with ajax this doesn't work.

any idea how i could solve that?

I wrote this animated scroll script with jquery that animates the jump when clicking on anchors.

```
/*Animated scroll for anchorlinks*/
    var anchor = '',
        pageOffset = '',
        viewOffset = 30,
        scrollPos = '';
    $(function() {
        $("a[href*='#']").each(function() {
            $(this).addClass('anchorLink');
            $(this).bind('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                anchor = $(this).attr('href').split('#')[1];
                pageOffset = $("a[name='#"+anchor+"']").offset();
                scrollPos = pageOffset.top - viewOffset;
                $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:scrollPos}, '500');
            })      
        });
    });
```

Any idea how i could solve that? thank you

Comment: "However since i'm loading the anchor with ajax this doesn't work." How are you loading your anchor with ajax?

Comment: I'm simply loading a div with some text and the anchor-link with the jquery load() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery Ajaxy has built in support for using ajax with hashes, as well as backwards support for traditional anchors - click the durian tab in the demo.

http://balupton.com/sandbox/jquery-ajaxy/demo/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [LearningJquery](http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/10/improved-animated-scrolling-script-for-same-page-links) approach or even using their plugin directly.
[Example](http://jsbin.com/ifaco3/9) of their approach.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var viewOffset = 30;
  function filterPath(string) {
  return string
 .replace(/^\//,'')
 .replace(/(index|default).[a-zA-Z]{3,4}$/,'')
 .replace(/\/$/,'');
  }
  var locationPath = filterPath(location.pathname);
  var scrollElem = scrollableElement('html', 'body');
  $('a[href*=#]').each(function() {
 var thisPath = filterPath(this.pathname) || locationPath;
 if (  locationPath == thisPath
 && (location.hostname == this.hostname || !this.hostname)
 && this.hash.replace(/#/,'') ) {
   var $target = $(this.hash), target = this.hash;
   if (target) {
  var targetOffset = $target.offset().top - viewOffset;
  $(this).click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(scrollElem).animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 400, function() {
   location.hash = target;
    });
  });
   }
 }
  });
  // use the first element that is "scrollable"
  function scrollableElement(els) {
 for (var i = 0, argLength = arguments.length; i <argLength; i++) {
   var el = arguments[i],
    $scrollElement = $(el);
   if ($scrollElement.scrollTop()> 0) {
  return el;
   } else {
  $scrollElement.scrollTop(1);
  var isScrollable = $scrollElement.scrollTop()> 0;
  $scrollElement.scrollTop(0);
  if (isScrollable) {
    return el;
  }
   }
 }
 return [];
  }
});
```